# Seleccionar todos los checkbox de un details, sin seleccionar los demás

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, php7

Estoy realizando una página que va a permitir a un grupo de profesores, pedir materiales para realizar su formación. Lo estoy programando para que sea una especie de "añadir al carrito"; para lograrlo, estoy usando checkbox y la información es traída desde una base de datos en MySQL.

Los productos, se dividen por áreas y posteriormente, en categorías que las agrupan mejor. Para mostrar estos detalles, estoy usando los . Necesito que, al seleccionar la categoría al que pertenece el producto, se seleccionen los checkboxes que pertenecen sólo a ese grupo sin que me seleccione los demás. Este es el código JavaScript que uso:

```
        function marcar(source) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); //obtenemos todos los controles del tipo Input
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) //recorremos todos los controles
        {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") //solo si es un checkbox entramos
            {
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked; //si es un checkbox le damos el valor del checkbox que lo llamó (Marcar/Desmarcar Todos)
            }
        }
    }
```

El problema de este código, es que me selecciona los checkbox pertenecientes a ese grupo, pero también me selecciona todos los checkbox que existen, incluso los que no pertenecen al programa del producto.

Este es el PHP:

```
    <section id="muestreo">
    <?php
    $programas=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM programas");
    while ($prog=mysqli_fetch_array($programas)) {
        echo "<font id='carrito' name='carrito' method='POST'>";
        echo "<details class='programa'>";
        echo "<summary>";
        echo $prog['nombre_prog'];
        $id=$prog['id_prog'];
        echo "</summary>";
        $productos=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos GROUP BY sub_categoria_prod");
        while($prod=mysqli_fetch_array($productos)){
            echo "<details class='hijo'>";
            echo "<summary>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' onclick='marcar(this);'>";
            echo $prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            echo "</summary>";
            $categoria=$prod['sub_categoria_prod'];
            $id=$prog['id_prog'];
            $informacion=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE sub_categoria_prod='$categoria' AND id_prog='$id'");
            while ($i=mysqli_fetch_array($informacion)) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $i['cod_prod'] . "'>";
                echo "<table border='1'class='tabla'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre del producto (SIBOL).</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><strong>" . $i['sibol_prod'] . "</strong></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Nombre comercial del producto.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['nombre_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Calidad.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['calidad_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Generalidades.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['generalidades_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos generales.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_generales_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Requisitos espec&iacute;ficos.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['re_espe_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Empaque y rotulado.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['empaque_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Presentaci&oacute;n.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'>" . $i['presentacion_prod'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th class='titulos'>Imagen de referencia.</th>";
                echo "<td class='generalidades'><img src='" . $i['imagen_prod'] . "' id='referencia'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
            echo "</details>";
        }
        echo "</details>";
        echo "</font>";
    }
    ?>
</section>
```

Sé que es extenso, pero para que tengan una mejor idea de lo que hago. Por favor, necesito alguien que me ayude y de ante mano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Algo así: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqJQRe ? Si es así solo veo que te falta agrupar los checkbox y relacionarlos a su "categoría" como en el ejemplo que te dejo.

Comment: Exactamente así. ¿Lo puedo copiar de ese ejemplo, o te puedo pedir algo adaptado?

Comment: Es mil veces mejor que lo intentes tú. Te podemos guiar en cada paso. Mira el ejemplo y si no entiendes algo o si no funciona, acá estamos! (Empieza por darle un nombre y un valor a los checkbox de los grupos)